# Facebook post as page in Swift 4

Tags: facebook

I want to show my posts on a Facebook business page, but it doesn't show the visitors sections. How can I fix that?

```
let params = [
                "access_token":"page_access_token",
                "caption":"Catption Message",
                "url":imageURL,
                "appId":FBSDKAccessToken.current().appID,
                "uid":FBSDKAccessToken.current().userID]

            FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "\(pageId)/photos", parameters: params, httpMethod: "POST").start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
```

Comment: Is your code complete ?

Comment: Most likely what you think is a page access token isn’t actually one, but a user token …